# Can't we get seven list-style comply with the sasme class?

Tags: css, cursor, html-lists, display

I'm facing a very strange, unexplainable issue for the first time in my old Web experience:
my page is quite linear and simple, involving a sequence of `<UL>` followed by seven `<LI class=book>`
where `.book` is `{list-style: url('book.png'); cursor:pointer;}`.

Well, the 7th "book" doesn't load the cursor and doesn't work with `onclick="showhide(what...)"` like all the others do; only the following text content does it.

Then I have inverted the position of the last two items, to check if one was defective, but again the last one only did not work as expected.

Adding one more does the same, none works right after the 6th.

Can somebody explain the reason?
How to obtain all to behave the same?

The page and its code is [easier to view](https://www.myway.it) than to describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a div with `title=" This domain was 'born'...` that is covering that exact corner with the book icon. Try removing/resizing that div so it doesn't cover elements.

Answer (score 0):

Right! I couldn't find out that, because the world map was not visible in local debugging;
I've spent hours trying everything else…
But no need to change the layout: enough to complete the class as

```
.book{ list-style: url('book.png'); cursor:pointer; **position:relative; z-index:50;**}
```